# azure permission denied on ftp an kudu

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-apps

We are trying to deploy a website via ftp and cannot connect:

```
Response:   331 Password required   
Command:    PASS ************************************************************  
Response:   530 User cannot log in.   
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

- i've already tried to reset the publish profile
- tried to deploy via vs19 with the new publish profile

i also tried to create a new web app but there was also an error:

```
{
  "Code": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "Message": "Storage access failed. Storage access failure - please retry later. Please delete and recreate backup schedule to mitigate.",
  "Target": null,
  "Details": [
    {
      "Message": "Storage access failed. Storage access failure - please retry later. Please delete and recreate backup schedule to mitigate."
    },
    {
      "Code": "ServiceUnavailable"
    },
    {
      "ErrorEntity": {
        "ExtendedCode": "04202",
        "MessageTemplate": "Storage access failed. {0}. Please delete and recreate backup schedule to mitigate.",
        "Parameters": [
          "Storage access failure - please retry later"
        ],
        "Code": "ServiceUnavailable",
        "Message": "Storage access failed. Storage access failure - please retry later. Please delete and recreate backup schedule to mitigate."
      }
    }
  ],
  "Innererror": null
}
```

When i try to delete, create or open something with kudu console i get a permission denied error.

Is there an issue with azure in west europe? (i dont see something on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/)

it worked like an hour ago....